# Can I use a foreach loop on Seed method operations with Entity Framework 6 - Update-Database command

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Mainly I'm trying to insert all cities data coming from an Xml using a foreach loop to iterate through each state.
We have more than 5000 city records, and this was the only approach I could come up with.

> ```
>         // Cities Seeding
>         foreach (var uf in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Uf)))
>         {
>             XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
>             xmlDoc.Load("http://servicos.cptec.inpe.br/~rserv/estados/cidade-" + uf.ToString() + ".xml");
>             int cityId = Convert.ToInt32(xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/climas/clima/estados/estado/cidades/cidade").Attributes["id"].Value);
>             string cityName = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/climas/clima/estados/estado/cidades/cidade").Attributes["nome"].Value.ToString();
>             bool capital = Convert.ToBoolean(xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/climas/clima/estados/estado/cidades/cidade").Attributes["capital"].Value);
>             int stateId = 1;
>             //if (!capital)
>             //{
>             context.Cities.AddOrUpdate(
>                 c => c.CityId,
>                 new City
>                 {
>                     CityId = cityId,
>                     CityName = cityName,
>                     StateId = stateId
>                 });
>             //}
>             //else
>             //{
>             //context.Capitals.AddOrUpdate(
>             //    cp => cp.CityId,
>             //    new Capital
>             //    {
>             //        CityId = cityId,
>             //        CityName = cityName,
>             //        StateId = stateId
>             //    });
>             //}
>             stateId++;
>         }
> ```

I'm not sure if makes any difference in this case but, State Id is a foreign key from States Table.

This is my error message:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> Npgsql.NpgsqlException: ERROR: 23503: insert or update on table "City" violates foreign key constraint "FK_public.City_public.States_StateId"
>
> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: Have you seeded the states table yet? You need to use the ID from the states table.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear that you're violating the foreign key constriant for City -> State. So does a State exist with an ID of 1?

Comment: @AndresCastro I'm assuming it's seeded because their records are being seeded before cities.

Comment: @Brandon according to my previous seeds, it should exist :/

Comment: `int stateId = 1;` should be declared **outside before** the `foreach`.

Comment: @Hopeless Thanks for you heads up, I've realized that afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Sirwan said, the exception you are seeing is telling you that you are violating the foreign key constraint to the states table. Judging by the FK name, it looks like you are using a `stateId` value that doesn't exist in the `States` table

> insert or update on table "City" violates foreign key constraint "FK_public.City_public.States_StateId

You also said:

> State Id is a foreign key from States Table

So, I'm assuming that the States table is a pre-populated table with the state records already in it. In other words, the states are not being inserted based on the XML file. Is that the case?

Your code also makes two main assumptions:

1. It assumes that the number of items in the `Uf` enum is less than or equal to the number of records in the `States` table.
2. It assumes that the items in the `Uf` enum are sorted matching the records in the `States` table sorted by `StatedId` ascending.

If assumption 1 is invalid, i.e. you have more records in the `Uf` enum than you have in the `States` table, you will try to insert records using a stateId that doesn't exist.

if assumption 2 is invalid, i.e. the `Uf` enum elements are not sorted matching the `stateId` in the `States` table, you will insert the cities to the wrong state.

Based on the exception you posted, I bet that assumption 1 is invalid, that the number of records on the `Uf` enum doesn't match the number of records in the `States` table. Or, the other option is that the `StateId` values in the `States` table doesn't match the raw number of elements in the enum.

For example, I saw that you are from Brasil, where we have 27 states. Here we have three options for your error:

1. `States` table doesn't have all the 27 states
2. The `StateId` values in the `States` table don't start from 1
3. The `StateId` values in the `States` table are not contiguous, i.e. they don't go from 1-27 but have gaps like :`1,2,3,6,7,8,9 ...`

In all the scenarios above, your code would end up using an invalid `stateId` that will violate the FK constraint.

The less brittle way to write this code, while possibly paying a small performance tax, would be iterate over the values of the `State` table instead of using the `Uf` enum. That way, you can make sure that the `StateId` value that you are assigning to the record matches the one from the table:

```
foreach (var state in context.States)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load("http://servicos.cptec.inpe.br/~rserv/estados/cidade-" + state.Name + ".xml");
    int cityId = Convert.ToInt32(xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/climas/clima/estados/estado/cidades/cidade").Attributes["id"].Value);
    string cityName = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/climas/clima/estados/estado/cidades/cidade").Attributes["nome"].Value.ToString();

    context.Cities.AddOrUpdate(
        c => c.CityId,
        new City
        {
            CityId = cityId,
            CityName = cityName,
            StateId = state.StateId
        });
}
```

Comment: In the end, I found out we were just missing a context.SaveChanges(); before starting to seed the cities.

Answer (score 0):

This error is telling you that you are violating the foreign key constraint. Check that there is not existing data in the database that is conflicting with the FK constraint causing the creation to fail.

**One more thing**: Why do you increment the `stateId`? As you mentioned you have more than 5000 city records, So the State table must contains more than records too.

Comment: I'm incrementing stateId because previously when I attempted to get the ID from the database itself I wasn't able to do so. Maybe because at that moment we still don't have States table with its records on the database?

Comment: @HenriqueCruz if the states table doesn't have the records yet, when you try to insert the records for the cities it will violate the FK constraint. It's not an EF issue. It's because you are indeed violating the FK constraint.

Comment: I get that, my problem is... Why am I violating anything here, if right before trying to insert this cities table, I've just inserted states table.

Comment: Or at least I think I did @Pedro

Answer (score 0):

This is how my code looked in the end:

```
context.SaveChanges();

    //Cities Seeding
    int stateId = 1;
    foreach (var uf in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Uf)))
    {

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load("http://servicos.cptec.inpe.br/~rserv/estados/cidade-" + uf.ToString() + ".xml");
        XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/climas/clima/estados/estado/cidades/cidade");
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            int cityId = Convert.ToInt32(node.Attributes["id"].Value);
            string cityName = node.Attributes["nome"].Value.ToString();
            bool cityIsCapital = Convert.ToBoolean(node.Attributes["capital"].Value);
            context.Cities.AddOrUpdate(
            c => c.CityId,
            new City()
            {
                CityId = cityId,
                CityName = cityName,
                CityIsCapital = cityIsCapital,
                StateId = stateId
            });
        }
        stateId++;
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why I've been banned